# Add JavaScript object to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, addition

I'd like to have JavaScript objects within another JavaScript object as such:

```
Issues:

  - {"ID" : "1", "Name" : "Missing Documentation", "Notes" : "Issue1 Notes"}
  - {"ID" : "2", "Name" : "Software Bug", "Notes" : "Issue2 Notes, blah, blah"}
  - {"ID" : "2", "Name" : "System Not Ready", "Notes" : "Issue3 Notes, etc"}
  // etc...
```

So, I'd like "Issues" to hold each of these JavaScript objects, so that I can just say Issues[0].Name, or Issues[2].ID, etc.

I've created the outer Issues JavaScript object:

```
var jsonIssues = {};
```

I'm to the point where I need to add a JavaScript object to it, but don't know how. I'd like to be able to say:

```
Issues<code here>.Name = "Missing Documentation";
Issues<code here>.ID = "1";
Issues<code here>.Notes = "Notes, notes notes";
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Per answers given, declared an array, and am pushing JavaScript objects on as needed:

```
var jsonArray_Issues = new Array();

jsonArray_Issues.push( { "ID" : id, "Name" : name, "Notes" : notes } );
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: There are a lot of answers instructing you to convert to an array (and I see you did in the end). I know this is an old question, but there is a new solution.
For anybody coming to this looking for an answer to the question of how to add an object to an object, please look at Object.assign. (it's new but this question comes up high on searches) I spent a lot of time looking for a solution to this that didn't involve creating an array and then converting it back. Here is the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
var jsonIssues = []; // new Array
jsonIssues.push( { ID:1, "Name":"whatever" } );
// "push" some more here
```

Comment: @jldupont, Thanks for the answer! I wasn't thinking in terms of arrays when I asked the question. But this makes sense.

Comment: would this work for unshift also because i wanted to add the object on the first position.

Answer (score 41):

As my first object is a native JavaScript object (used like a list of objects), `push` didn't work in my scenario, but I resolved it by adding new key as follows:

```
MyObjList['newKey'] = obj;
```

In addition to this, may be useful to know how to delete the same object as inserted before:

```
delete MyObjList['newKey'][id];
```

Hope it helps someone as it helped me.

Comment: This seems like the best technical answer to the op's original question.

Answer (score 9):

```
var jsonIssues = [
 {ID:'1',Name:'Some name',Notes:'NOTES'},
 {ID:'2',Name:'Some name 2',Notes:'NOTES 2'}
];
```

If you want to add to the array then you can do this

```
jsonIssues[jsonIssues.length] = {ID:'3',Name:'Some name 3',Notes:'NOTES 3'};
```

Or you can use the push technique that the other guy posted, which is also good.

Comment: So essentially, I'll have an array of JSON objects?

Comment: I believe the OP would also like to know how to *add* objects to what you have.

Comment: You'll have an array of JavaScript objects. JSON is just a serialization that happens to conform to a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you can add to it as if it was an array built manually

Answer (score 6):

// Merge object2 into object1, recursively

```
$.extend( true, object1, object2 );
```

// Merge object2 into object1

```
$.extend( object1, object2 );
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 4):

If it's not an array of object you can do this:

```
let student= {
  name : 'Mr. Anderson',
  id: 35
}

student['grade'] = 10; //for a property.
```

Result:

```
student= {
  name : 'Mr. Anderson',
  id: 35,
  grade:10
}
```

You also can add an object:

```
let student= {
 personalData:{
  //personal data key-value
 }
}

let academicData = {
 //academic data key-value
}

student['academicData'] = academicData;
```

Result:

```
 student{
        personalData{},
        academicData{}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jsonIssues = [...jsonIssues,{ID:'3',Name:'name 3',Notes:'NOTES 3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have properties in first obj and you **have to add** your objs to it, then Object.assign() will erase it.

To avoid this loss I've written a function below. Be aware, it copies nested objs by refference.

First you should add all objs you want to add to your's obj to an arr. You can do it easily by arr.push(). Then just use the Fn.

```
function addMyObjs (objInit, arrWithObjs) {
    let map = new Map();
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(objInit)) {
        map.set(key, value);
    }
    arrWithObjs.forEach((item) => {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
            map.set(key, value);
        }
    });
    return Object.fromEntries(map);
}

let objSecond = {id: 2,};

let obj = {
    name: "Tolya",
    age: 33,
    sex: "man",
};

let obj3 = {"fruits": {"apples": true, "plums": false,}};

let arr = [obj, obj3];

objSecond = addMyObjs(objSecond, arr);
```